# Apply typescript using react

Tags: typescript

```
<Test>
      {({
        direction,
        filteredItems,
        onItemSelectAll,
        onItemSelect,
        selectedKeys: listSelectedKeys,
        disabled: listDisabled,
      }) => {
        const columns = direction === 'left' ? leftColumns : rightColumns;
.......
```

In my case i use typescript so when i try to run the code, for this part of the code appear an error: `Binding element 'direction' implicitly has an 'any' type`
So, now i want to now how to apply typescript, because I tried to write `direction:any` but i got `'any' is declared but its value is never read.`
 How to apply typescript in this situation? I mean the block between `direction` to `disabled`?

Comment: What do you mean, exactly, by *apply typescript in this situation*? The question is unclear

Answer (score 1):

Are you destructuring the function's argument? If yes, I think the way to do it in TypeScript is like this :

```
interface Args {
  direction: any
  selectedKeys: listSelectedKeys
  disabled: listDisabled
}

({ direction, selectedKeys, disabled }: Args) => {
  // on hover, direction is of 'any' type
  console.log(direction)
}
```

Comment: Or you can omit the `interface` and *inline* the type definition but this way is cleaner

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to specify type for destructered object properties, if that's the case try this

```
<Test>
      {({
    direction,
    filteredItems,
    onItemSelectAll,
    onItemSelect,
    selectedKeys: listSelectedKeys,
    disabled: listDisabled
  }: {
    direction: any;
    filteredItems: any;
    onItemSelectAll: any;
    onItemSelect: any;
    selectedKeys: { listSelectedKeys: any };
    disabled: { listDisabled: any };
  }) => { const columns = direction === 'left' ? leftColumns : rightColumns;
```

Instead of `any`, just use whichever type you need there.